# User still able to connect to DB even though their account has been removed, and guest dropped

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a user that I am trying to show security for SQL Databases too, but I have run into an issue I am not sure makes any sense. I dropped their account completely, as well as the "guest" account on our DB using:

```
DROP USER [guest]
GO
DROP USER [JoeB]
GO
```

Yet when he then tries to reconnect, he can, and when I get him to run the following query:

```
select current_user as me;
```

It says the user is "guest"

How is this possible? We have no other accounts on this DB except mine, the two other DBAs, and a coworker who uses the DB for reporting with Tableau.

Am I forgetting a simple step here?

Any advice is appreciated!

Edit: I also executed REVOKE CONNECT FROM GUEST. with no results.

Edit 2: Discovered one of the other DBAs had set up his User to be a gateway for anyone who was connected to our network was able to access our sql server, and all of it's databases. After deleting this account, we now are back to everything working normally!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot drop guest from a SQL server db.

You can, however, REVOKE CONNECT FROM GUEST.

Comment: I did that as well, and he was still able to connect.

Comment: Did you drop JoeB from master, or just from the db in question? Try:
`USE master
    GO
    DROP LOGIN [JoeB]
    GO`

Keep us posted...

Comment: I did not, but he is unable to even connect to our other DBs that he has never been added too, just this test DB that I created a user for him. Why is he unable to view these other DBs?

Comment: perhaps he doesn't have a user on those databases? Note the difference between a LOGIN and a USER. I had to wrap my head around it, too...

Comment: Right, but I dropped his user on this DB, as seen above?

Comment: Right, so I'm curious to see what happens when you drop his LOGIN. I think that will corner the correct answer.

Comment: You could also go check out his LOGINs properties before you do... look for anything strange.

Comment: SSMS: [database engine] >> Security >> Logins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156483/discussion-between-sqlcliff-and-cody-cook).